# Need help making this method (using string.Join() and LINQ) into a generic one

Tags: c#, string, linq, generics, join

I wrote a function that converts the values of a DataTable into a string formatted as "value1, value2, value3, ...". The function also takes in the columnindex as well as a surrounder (usually "'") as an argument.

Rather than writing lots of different variations of this function (e.g. one with a dataset, one with a List, etc.) I'd like to make only 1 function for this which is generic.

I've tried to add  and IEnumerable to the function header already but then getting the "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'T'" error inside the function.

I think I need to make an interface for this to work (?) but I don't have much/any experience with that.

This is the original function that I want to make into a generic one:

```
public static string GenerateWhereInListFromData(DataTable dt_data, int columnIndex, string separator)
{
    string resultList = string.Join(", ", dt_data.AsEnumerable().Select(tmp => separator + tmp[columnIndex].ToString() + separator));

    return resultList;
}
```

Can any one help with how to make this into a generic function which can take a dataset, a datatable, a string array, a list and possibly other stuff as an input parameter?

Comment: If you doing this to generate a sql query `.. WHERE Column IN ('value1', 'value2', 'value3', ...)` - don't, because of possible Sql Injection and performance reasons. Instead you can use [Table-Valued Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

short explentation:

Maybe your Methode that fails looks like:

```
public static string GenerateWhereInListFromDataFail<T>(IEnumerable<T> dt_data, int columnIndex, string separator) 
        {
            return string.Join(", ", dt_data.Select(tmp => separator + tmp[columnIndex].ToString() + separator));;
        }
```

So the problem that you have is the accessor for the column.
One solution to resolve the problem could be to delegate the work.

```
public static string GenerateWhereInListFromData<T>(IEnumerable<T> dt_data, Func<T, string> columnAccessor, string separator) 
    {
        return string.Join(", ", dt_data.Select(tmp => separator + columnAccessor(tmp) + separator));;
    }
```

The call of the method looks like:

```
GenerateWhereInListFromData(new List<System.Data.DataRow>(), t => t[0].ToString(), ",");
```

I hope i could help you.

**Edited part:**

---

To answer the question in your comment.
You don't need to define some other Methods to interact with the different types.
You just need to get shure you could work with all as IEnumerable.

Maybe some Code could explain what i try to say:

```
System.Data.DataSet dataSet = null;
var result = GenerateWhereInListFromData(dataSet.Tables.Cast<System.Data.DataTable>(), t => t.TableName, ",");

System.Data.DataTable dataTable = null;
result = GenerateWhereInListFromData(dataTable.Rows.Cast<System.Data.DataRow>(), t => t["SomeColumn"].ToString(), ",");
result = GenerateWhereInListFromData(dataTable.Columns.Cast<System.Data.DataColumn>(), t => t.ColumnName, ",");
```

The extentionmethod .Cast() do the job very well. It casts all the inner objects to some IEnumerable.

So the results could look like this:

Table1,Table2,Table3,

Value1,Value2,Value3,

Column1,Column2,Column3,

Comment: Hello, thanks for your detailed response!

Yes, my "Fail" Method looks pretty much exactly like that!

I'm still very new to delegate and such, I know it's a pointer to a function essentially but I still lack any practice.

Do I have to write a function columnAccess that takes in a generic and returns a string and then add all cases for DataTable, DataSet, etc. inside? Would you be able to provide me one simple example what it'd look like?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought I need to define another method, but it's basically just being passed as a lambda expression. 

So I noticed that I can just pass in my DataTable as dt.AsEnumerable() as well or a DataSet as ds.Tables[xxx].AsEnumerable(). That's what I needed. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

For the generic function to work, you need to find an interface that works for all types passed in, like iList, ICollection, IEnumerable, etc. If you can't find an interface for all of that, try checking the object's type for all those interfaces and have code that will copy the data to a list that you then Join.